# How to integrate this equation

Tags: integration, gamma-function

all.
I am trying integrate this equation(gamma density).
$$\int\limits_0^\infty  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left| x-1 \right|}}\exp \left( -\left| 1-x \right| \right) \;dx$$

What I have done is split it into 2 cases, but stuck on integrating with square root.

$$f(x)=  \begin{cases}
   \int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\exp \left( -(1-x) \right)}\;dx & x<1  \\
   \int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\exp \left( -(x-1) \right)}\;dx & x>1  \\
\end{cases}$$

How do I integrate each one?  Thanks!

Comment: Integration by parts, haven't tried that but looks like it should work! Also, these integrals might have come up in Probability but they are questions about integrals more than about Probability. So I have retagged. May be this is related to $\Gamma$ integrals in the form of $\Chi^2(n)$ distibutions

Comment: "Equation" is another frequently mis-used word.  The thing you're trying to integrate is a _function_.

Comment: In second integral, let $x-1=\frac{u^2}{2}$. Similar substitution for first integral.

Comment: thanks for retag Kannappan.  Michael, I wasn't trying to say things in the simplest way possible, but I agree with your point.  André, can you elaborate?  Wouldn't this be applicable to first equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the former integral, the substitution $u=\sqrt{1-x}$ gives

$$\int_1^0 e^{-u^2}(-2du)=\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}(1). $$

In the latter integral, the substitution $u=\sqrt{x-1}$ gives

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}(2du)=\sqrt{\pi}.$$

Put them together and we have $\sqrt{\pi}\big(1+\operatorname{erf}(1)\big)$. Here $\operatorname{erf}$ is the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: Thanks, anon.  Pretty thorough answer.  Does this entire thing integrate to 1?  Doesn't look like it with the erf(1) function.

Comment: @user1061210: Have you heard of [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)? Go there and enter `Sqrt[Pi]*(1+Erf[1])`; the answer is about 3.27. In order to normalize the integral (to evaluate to 1) you need to divide by $\sqrt{\pi}(1+\operatorname{erf}(1))$, obviously.

Comment: HOLD ON, you meant 1 to infinity on the second integral(latter sum) correct?

Comment: @user106120: I do not. The map $x\mapsto\sqrt{x-1}$ takes the bounds $[1,\infty)$ and gives us the new bounds $[0,\infty)$. When doing substitutions you always have to pay attention to how the interval of integration changes. The entire reason that second integral is so easily evaluable is because it is just the Gaussian integral.

Comment: Also, not sure why I called them sums. I've edited that.

Comment: @ your first comment, I get it.  How about the first integral shouldn't it be 0 to 1?

Comment: @user: (Ignore the chat warning) Nope. The function $\sqrt{1-x}$ takes $0$ to $1$ and vice-versa. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$ (abusing notation), which explains why the minus sign in the integral disappears.

Comment: Did you just add a negative sign? lol.  Or did I miss reading it?  Anywho, everything makes sense now.

Comment: @user: Do you know how to do substitution?

Comment: I have no idea if you are being sarcastic or not, in the case you are not, the answer is yes.

Comment: I was not being sarcastic. The negative sign in the equation comes from $du = \color{Red}-\frac{1}{2}dt/u$. The substitution switches the end points to $\int_1^0$, which by the fundamental theorem we can switch back to $\color{Blue}- \int_0^1$. These two negative signs cancel each other out.

Answer (score 4):

The second one is easy (with $x-1=t^2$) :
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac1{\sqrt{t^2}} e^{-t^2} 2t\ dt=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi}$$

The first one (with $1-x=t^2$) gives :
$$-\int_1^0 \frac1{\sqrt{t^2}} e^{-t^2} 2t\ dt=2\int_0^1 e^{-t^2}dt= \sqrt{\pi} \ \mathrm{erf}(1)$$ by definition of the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

Comment: Thanks, Raymond.  This is very clear!  Also asked the commenter above, does this integrate to 1?  If not, I want it to, which would be 1 divided by the result?

Comment: @user1061210: Thanks! As anon answered very clearly you'll have to divide by $\sqrt{\pi}(1+\mathrm{erf}(1))\ $ if you want $1$.

Comment: wait, the bounds you give are not the same as the question.